# NDK API for ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore

Is there any plans for an NDK API for the ARCore? Something of the line of the Tango's NDK API allowing you to get the values ARCore has fetched from the environment and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARCore Developer Preview 2 now supports C API:
https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton this is not a tool or a library, this is the link to the C SDK of ArCore

Answer (score 0):

ARcore package is newer version of Tango Core. They replaced motion tracking source but API for it stays the same, point cloud API is of course completely different.

Anyway what I want to say: it should be possible to open Tango NDK example set libtango_device require on false:

and maybe some of these examples can work with ARcore.

Answer (score 0):

Ar core Supports NDK already. There is a nice sample project for it as well:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/quickstart